# puts "nil" if it is not in range

Tags: ruby

```
def binary_search(num, test_array)
  counter = 0
  low = 0
  high = test_array.length

  while (low <= high) do
    i = ((low + high) / 2).floor;
    if num == test_array[i]
      return i
      break
    elsif num < test_array[i]
      high = i
    elsif num > test_array[i]
      low = i
    end
    counter += 1
  end
end

test_array = [13, 19, 24, 29, 32, 37, 43]
# binary_search(35, test array)?
# binary_search(11, test array)?
```

in this code, how can I make sure it will return "nil" if it is  binary_search(35), or binary_search(11)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, doesn't a `return nil` or simply `nil` after the while loop work?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. In your current code, it seems an infinite loop when an element isn't found. After fixing that, modifying the return value is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @YuHao, it's an infinite loop when your element isn't found as: `low = high = 0` (on the lower end) which makes the loop run indefinitely.

```
def binary_search(num, test_array)
  counter = 0
  low = 0
  high = test_array.length

  while (low <= high) do
    i = ((low + high) / 2).floor;
    if num == test_array[i]
      return i
    elsif num < test_array[i]
      high = i
    elsif num > test_array[i]
      low = i
    end
    counter += 1

    break if counter > test_array.length / 2 # could probably be more efficient
  end

  nil
end

test_array = [13, 19, 24, 29, 32, 37, 43]

binary_search(11, test_array) # => nil
binary_search(35, test_array) # => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

As Yu Hao mentioned, when nothing is found, it goes into an infinite loop.
Here is an example of checking for the infinite loop case and return nil.

```
def binary_search(num, test_array)
  counter = 0
  low = 0
  high = test_array.length

  while (low <= high) do
    i = ((low + high) / 2).floor;
    if num == test_array[i]
      return i
      break
    elsif num < test_array[i]
      high = i
    elsif num > test_array[i]
      low = i
    end
    counter += 1

    # check for value not found
    if (high - low) <= 1
      return nil
    end

  end
end
```